# Failed to resolve i18n-t component and t directive - Vue-i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-i18n

I have integrated the [Vue I18n](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/) plugin into my project and for some reason it is not working 100% correctly.

`globalInjection` is set to `true` in my configuration as follows:

```
const i18n = createI18n({
    fallbackLocale: defaultLocale,
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true // <-- See here
});
```

The following **does work** in an SFC:

```
<h1>{{ $t('views.home.body.some_key') }}</h1>
```

However, if I try to use the `<i18n-t>` custom component, or the `v-t` custom directive, I get the following errors:

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: i18n-t

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: t

I have read through the documentation numerous times now but still cannot find clear instructions as to how to inject the component and directive globally. I had assumed that `globalInjection` would have handled this, but for some reason, it hasn't.

Am I meant to be using `usei18n()` in my SFC? I have tried this, and it threw the same error...

Not sure if it is relevant, but I am using Webpack. I also read something about needing to put something into the webpack configuration but again, the documentation is extremely unclear...

### Update

My `app.js` looks like this (key parts extracted):

```
import { i18n } from './utils/i18n/index.js';

app.use(i18n);
```

and the `./utils/i18n/index.js` looks like this:

```
const setupI18n = () => {

    const defaultLocale = config.locales.default.toLowerCase();

    const i18n = createI18n({
        fallbackLocale: defaultLocale,
        legacy: false,
        globalInjection: true
    });

    loadLocaleTranslations(i18n, defaultLocale);

    setLocale(i18n, getLocale());

    registerI18nMiddleware(i18n, router);

    window.onlanguagechange = () => {
        setLocale(i18n, getLocaleFromBrowser() ?? getLocale());
    };

    return i18n;
};

const i18n = setupI18n();

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Please share the main.js

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim - I have updated the question with my configuration. Forgive me if I have missed out bits - I have tried to extract only the relevant parts

Comment: Your config looks fine

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - and that is why I am extremely confused... Could it be my SFCs? Am I meant to import anything?

Comment: did you register the plugin before mounting the app?

Comment: Could it be to do with my webpack configuration or should this just work out of the box? If my configuration is fine then it is obviously something that I am doing in the rest of my code and I can begin to debug it so I guess my simple question is; should the component and directive be automatically globally injected based on my configuration `globalInjection: true`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - at the bottom of my `app.js`, I have the following: `router.isReady().then(() => { app.mount('#app'); });`

Comment: globalInjection isn't responsible for this. Things like registering comps and dirs are handled by a plugin. Since you have `app.use(i18n)` and `$t` is there, it's expected that i18n-t and v-t are registered too and should work. usei18n is NOT needed, it's for accessing `t`, etc in script section. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask - It's probably going to be quite challenging to reproduce this given the size and complexity of my app. Perhaps it would be better to start by me sharing my full `app.js`? Can you advise where a good location is to do this as it's probably a bit long to paste into the question...

Comment: Stackblitz and Codesandbox or git repo, considering that the problem is reproducible with fresh project installation. Due to the nature of the problem, it's supposed to be reproducible with barebone main.js, i18.js and App.vue and your Webpack setup. I'm unaware of any conditions under which this could happen, I'd expect there's something wrong with package versions or Webpack config.

Comment: @EstusFlask - I'll do my best to get this uploaded to one of those providers (I'll start with app.js as there may be something obvious). My webpack configuration is quite complex - I would most likely have to upload the whole project in order to replicate this. Bear with me and I'll come back once I have got this up

Comment: I see the place that may be responsible for this behaviour. Try `app.use(i18n, { globalInstall: true })` first

Comment: @EstusFlask - negative - just tried that :-(

Comment: @EstusFlask - I found the issue!!! I knew it would be a simple one... In my webpack configuration, I had the following line: `__VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: false`. Setting this to true has fixed the issue. I'll look deeper into this as I want to make sure I am only bundling the features I intend to use

Comment: @EstusFlask - would you like to post up an answer so I can give you credit? I wouldn't have thought to check this if it wasn't for your suggestion...

Comment: Glad you figured it out with the right direction. I suppose it has to be a self-answer, I wasn't actually aware of this flag, although I see it's documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by the [`__VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__`](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/optimization.html#reduce-bundle-size-with-feature-build-flags) setting:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__: false,
    __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: false // <- This needs to be TRUE
})
```